# Can I SELECT this in a single stament?

Tags: mysql

I am a total SQL noob; sorry.

I have a table

```
mysql> describe activity;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user         | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| time_stamp   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| activity     | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| item         | int     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Normally `activity` is a two-step process; 1) "check out" and 2 "use"

An `item` cnnot be checked out a second time, unless used.

Now I want to find any cases where an item was checked out but not used.

Being dumb, I would use two selects, one for check out &one for use, on the same item, then compare the timestamps.

Is there a SELECT statemnt that will help me selct the items which were checked out but not used?

Tricky with the possibility of multipel checkouts. Or should I just code

```
loop over activity, form oldest until newset
  if find a checkout and there is no newer used time then i have a hit
```

Comment: What happens *after* the item has been used?  Is there a "check in" activity?  If not, what is the difference between an item that has been "checked out" then "used" and one that has been "used" then "checked out"?

Comment: you want to search each activity based on a date range, is that correct?

Comment: @eggyal  It is alwyas check out, then use. IF already checked out a further attemt will be rejected. So, I just look for checked out but not used (misisng, presumed stolen)

Comment: @sree +1 Can yu please tell me where I ddn't describe it correctly (always difficult to do) and then I can update the question & help you to help me. Thnaks

Comment: @Mawg in the first step , before you look for the activity make sure the daterange is described!

Comment: Hello @Mawg , you said it's a 2-step process. So, are you updating the table before checking out ? If so, when will you have "check-out" as activity ? When is the activity updated as "use" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the last date of each checkout or use and then compare them per item:

```
SELECT MAX(IF(activity='check out', time_stamp, NULL)) AS last_co, 
MAX(IF(activity='use', time_stamp, NULL)) AS last_use
FROM activity
GROUP BY item
HAVING NOT(last_use >= last_co);
```

The `NOT(last_use >= last_co)` is written that way because of how `NULL` compare behaviour works: `last_use` < `last_co` will not work if `last_use` is null.

Without proper indexing, this query will not perform very well though. Plus you might want to bound the query using a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Select * from activity where activity == "check out";
Your question is unclear, but I guess this might help.

Comment: @JAck. 1 Thanks., that seem to be what I am looking for. I will check it out

Comment: @xFortyFour +1. Srry if it is unclear. Can you please tell me how & I will attempt to clarify? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, is this a SO bug? I thought @xFortyFourx made a separate answer, but now it's lumped into mine as a comment? ;-)

Comment: @Jack, I'm sorry, that comment was meant for the question itself, accidentally made it on to yours :)